# Can't see categories in Stack Exchange all sites grid view

Tags: support

I remember that we have categories such as "Culture/Science……" on the StackExchange, however now I cannot see，Is it a change?

**You can see from the image: All, uncategoried……——only two.**

[image]

Comment: Can't reproduce, I see [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/AjRCf.png). Try clearing your cache and reloading.

Comment: Tried in IE,Chrome and Firefox but the same appears.....:(

Comment: This isn't working for me as well: http://imgur.com/ENfTDzj . Also, the footer's [more (21)](http://stackexchange.com/sites#culturerecreation) links don't work - I get the same page without any filters.

Comment: @ShadowWizard：Which explorer are you using?

Comment: Weird... I tried with Chrome (latest) and IE11, both logged in and as a visitor.

Comment: No repro http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=grid#culturerecreation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well……I found this "bug" did seem to be fixed....